# Detecting use of back/forward button inside Sammy.js application

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

In my current project we are using the Sammy.js framework for navigation. For a requirement I need to know whether a given route was run as a response of pressing the <kbd>Back</kbd>/<kbd>Forward</kbd> button or not.

Is there a way to identify that?

Comment: As I understood, there is no way to detect it. I opened an issue at GitHub, but there is no one who answered. https://github.com/quirkey/sammy/issues/199

Answer (score 0):

You can't know that precisely.
All you can find out is wether the navigation event was received from inside the application (click on a link handled by Sammy, form submited , action in your JS ...) or if the navigation event came from the "outside" Back Button, Forward button, change in the URL bar, ...